# How to maintain user session across different devices and browsers from the access code email link in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-email

After validating the user, I'm sending out the access token to the user's email, along with the link to come back to the same page.
[![Access Token email][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWezf.png

This works well when the user opens the email in the same browser in which he was previously validated, but if he opens the email on his mobile or some other browser and then clicks on the link, he is taken back to the validation page to enter his user details again.

How can I maintain the same session across multiple platforms in Django? I know methods exist that can accomplish that. For example, an API can take an encrypted request id as a parameter, which will be included as a token in the access code email link to the landing page. The API will decrypt the encrypted request id and then return the payload back, associated with the same request id, and the data can then be used on the front end to identify the user and resume the access-code verification step.

But I don't know how to implement that or if there is a better solution.